# Como verificar se um email existe mesmo?

Tags: php, email

Fiz um campo de email para o usuário se cadastrar, e agora preciso de um sistema que verifique se esse email existe.

Eu preciso que quando o usuário digite seu email um sistema verifique se ele existe, se ele possui mesmo esse email. Por exemplo o usuário digita: `usuário_03@gmail.com`, aí aparecerá do lado: *"email válido"* ou *"email inválido".*

Já pesquisei sistema de validação de emails mas não aparecem resultados concretos. Será que alguém pode me ajudar?

Comment: Embora não esteja claro parece muito amplo: há diversos sistemas de e-mail, cada um com suas particularidades. Se o autor fez um próprio ele deve próprio deveria saber como resolver isso.

Comment: Se você estiver usando um sistema de terceiros, como o Gmail, você só pode saber se o e-mail [é válido ou não](https://code.google.com/p/isemail/downloads/list). Caso esteja usando um sistema próprio faça como o [perdeu](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/8069/2804) disse. Ainda, caso for uma página de login só fale que algo está errado, por segurança.

Comment: Ainda há outras implicações, tais como: se o caso for um formulário de registro fale que o e-mail já está sendo usado; se estiver usando Google Apps, ou semelhante, use as APIs. Isso ainda varia da linguagem usada, comumente trabalhamos com PHP mas você pode usar outra: acho um pouco amplo.

Comment: Até onde sei, a resposta do do bfavaretto é a correta. Este post tem algumas coisas interessantes ([How to check if an email address exists without sending an email?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/565504/1287812)), mas no fim parece tudo bastante experimental.

Comment: Impossível de validar não é, mas dá trabalho e é preciso abrir a porta do Telnet! Veja explicação no artigo: > [Como testar se uma conta de email é válida/existe sem enviar um email](http://igorseiji.info/2012/02/14/como-testar-se-uma-conta-de-email-e-validaexiste-sem-enviar-um-email/),

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Sem a interação do usuário você só conseguirá verificar se o email é válido (bem-formado) ou não.

Embora o protocolo SMTP permita a verificação de contas, vários servidores de email deixaram de oferecer essa função devido ao [abuso dessa função por parte de spammers](https://web.archive.org/web/20140717092354/http://www.spamresource.com/2010/11/smtp-address-validation-bad-idea.html#Feed4).

Para checar se o email existe mesmo, é necessário criar um passo a mais no seu cadastro. Quando o usuário fizer o cadastro, registre seu status como "pendente" ou algo do tipo, e mande um email de confirmação para o endereço informado. O email deve conter um link único daquele usuário, como um hash do email informado + algum valor arbitrário como *salt*.

Quando o usuário acessar o link (que aponta para o seu sistema), você verifica o hash passado, e atualiza o status para "cadastrado".

Answer (score 13):

É impossível fazer uma validação definitiva de um endereço de email porque muitos servidores de SMTP de destino aceitam mensagens mesmo para endereços que não existem, e talvez só depois retornam uma mensagem para um remetente informando que o email não é válido.

No entanto o que você pode fazer é simular o envio de uma mensagem para o dado endereço de email e ver se o servidor de SMTP de destino aceitaria o destinatário.

Para isso precisa consultar o DNS para obter o registro MX do domínio informado e assim saber qual é o servidor ou quais são os servidores que receberiam a mensagem para esse domínio. Pode dar 1 servidor, vários ou até nenhum. Neste último caso o servidor a ser usado deve ser o do registro A do domínio.

Aí conecta na porta 25 de cada um dos servidores. Se um deles já recusar o destinatário, você já fica sabendo que é inválido. Se um deles aceitar, já fica sabendo que é válido. Se nenhum servidor aceitar a conexão ou der um erro com código 4XX, não dá para saber se é válido, pois é uma situação que pode ser temporária.

Implementar este algoritmo de forma adequada é um pouco trabalhoso. No entanto eu mesmo desenvolvi uma [classe de PHP para validação de email](http://www.phpclasses.org/package/13-PHP-Determine-if-a-given-e-mail-address-is-valid-.html) que já implementa esses passos todos e tem sido aprimorada desde 1999.

Para além disso a classe ainda permite que você defina uma lista de domínios que você nunca vai querer aceitar emails, como aqueles de emails temporários descartáveis.

Answer (score 9):

É bastante complexo por envolver diversas técnicas.
A técnica mais comum é o email com link de validação da conta. Ajuda bastante mas é insuficiente porque muitas vezes email cai na caixa de spam ou as vezes nem é enviado ou mesmo quando é válido, o usuário não se dá ao trabalho de clicar no link de validação.

Outra técnica é criar uma escuta no servidor do email de resposta.
Exemplo, envie um email de confirmação cujo email de resposta será para um email especial onde o servidor pop estará aguardando uma resposta.
Normalmente retorna mensagem "mail undeliverable" quando o servidor de destino recusa uma conta mesmo que tenha configuração para receber os "emails trash".
O filtro mais popular e fácil de implementar é com o `procmail`, sob sistemas Linux.

Mas tome cuidado quando marcar um email como inválido em definitivo porque pode ocorrer de um email inexistente passar a existir posteriormente.
Exemplo:

O `email1234@stackoverflow.com` provavelmente não existe.
Supondo-se que seja feito validação hoje, retornará como inválido.
Mas se amanhã alguém criar exatamente essa mesma conta?
Então, jamais marque um email como inválido de forma definitiva.

Answer (score 7):

Acho que vc poderia fazer o seguinte: Quando qualquer pessoa incluir o email e clicar em enviar, o seu sistema envia para ele uma mensagem que ele entra no email e faz a confirmação. Dai o seu sistema recebe a confirmação e cadastra. Se ele não confirmar, o seu sistema não faz o cadastro.

Answer (score 1):

Você pode enviar para o endereço de e-mail informado uma mensagem com link de validação de e-mail, assim que clicado o usuário é redirecionado para seu sistema e o email é dado como válido.

Existem outros serviços que fazem verificação de e-mail, segue link de um desses serviços mais famoso.

https://www.emailhippo.com/en-US/solutions