# Tratando possíveis erros de digitação em emails (@gamail, @hotnail ..)

Tags: angularjs, email, plugin

Bom, estou com alguns cadastros problemáticos por conta que o usuário digitou por ex: "josé@gamail.com".

Pelo que vi [nesta resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8067/como-verificar-se-um-email-existe-mesmo), a maioria dos servidores desabilitaram um possivel ping com resposta se o email existe, por conta de spammers.

Qual seria a solução que vocês usariam neste caso ?

Pensei em criar um plugin onde esses erros são tratados, por exemplo:

```
let emailError = false;
let emailValid = false;
let emailInserido = this.emailInserido;


if ( emailInserido === "gamail" || emailInserido === "gmil" ... ) {
  emailError = true;
} else {
emailValid = true; }
```

Comment: Você propõe uma abordagem diferente da pergunta marcada como duplicata, mas sua abordagem não é viável. Assim, acho que as perguntas recaem na mesma resposta.

Answer (score 4):

Não existe meio de confirmar se um e-mail existe diretamente. Isso porque, como você disse, o spam correria solto.

O que deve ser feito é gerar um código de ativação embutido em um link que é enviado para o e-mail, e que o usuário deve seguir (o link) para completar o cadastro. Você já fez isso em vários sites, como usuário.

Com relação a verificar o *domínio* (o que vem depois do @), talvez haja serviços que permitem essa verificação (não é possível você montar isso você mesmo para TODOS os domínios existentes). Não sei se compensaria o trabalho, o e-mail com link para confirmação resolve.

Finalmente, pense em usar autenticação delegada (acessar seu sistema através de uma conta no google, facebook, etc.). É fácil se a plataforma onde está desenvolvendo tem API (acho que sim), e evita que o usuário precise ficar lembrando de muitas senhas.

Comment: Realmente, fazer para todos os domínios seria muito trabalhoso.. mas pensando agora, acho que um auto-complete para os principais já diminuiria os erros.. na base que estou trabalhando é quase 70% dos usuários são @ gmail, @ hotmail, @ globo, @ oul.. e vou fazer como você falou, deixar o email como pendente até a confirmação.. pelo menos o usuário terá o feedback que tem algo errado..

Comment: Fazer um auto complete é uma _ótima_ idéia. Gostei. Pode usar como base todos os domínios que existem (e foram confirmados pelo link!) no seu sistema. Interessante!