# Corrigir registros de email incorretos

Tags: php, html, sql

Preciso corrigir via programação em PHP, emails incorretos cadastrados em nosso banco de dados.

Seriam emails sem domínio, com espaço em alguma posição, com ".@", "@.", sem "@", qualquer carácter não permitido no EMAIL.

Comment: Não sei se intendi oque você quer fazer, mas imagino que seria inutil tentar corrigir um email sem dominio, justamente por você não saber qual o dominio. Mas se for o caso de apenas remover alguns caracteres indesejados acho que você consegue fazer isso com regex: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_regular_expression.htm

Comment: Olá seja bem vindo ao Stack Overflow @AlanHenrique, poderia postar o que já tem tentado?

Comment: Corrigir, seria excluir esses registro do banco de dados? Qual banco de dados? Seria melhor fazer direto no banco. Ou voce quer quando incluir um registro errado via front, o back já ignorar e nem gravar esses registros?

Comment: PHP já tem função própria pra isso. RegEx + email geralmente só dá desastres. A regra pra email fica muito grande e complexa. Tem um monte de gente que divulga umas RegEx simplificadas demais em sites, fuja disso. Se for usar RegEx se limite a isso que falou, verificar se tem arroba, espaço, e se tem um ponto ao menos a direita, no máximo isso. É frustrante para um usuário tentar cadastrar um email válido, e não conseguir. Muito pior do que passar um inválido (e, de qualquer forma, só vai saber se um email é válido de fato ao fazer um envio com sucesso).

Comment: @Bacco poderia ser uma resposta

Comment: @Math eu tenho quase certeza que é dup, só nao deu tempo de procurar.

Comment: @Bacco essa? http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/8067/3117

Comment: @Math acho que essa: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/8134/verificar-se-vari%c3%a1vel-cont%c3%a9m-um-endere%c3%a7o-de-email-bem-formatado-em-php